# How to use readClipboard to read a bitmap when using R?

Tags: r, bitmap, clipboard

I don't managed to read a bitmap which is in the Windows clipbard.
I first check the cliboard :

```
getClipboardFormats()
```

which give

> [1] "bitmap" "DIB"    "shell"

Then I tried :

```
image = readClipboard(format=2, raw=FALSE)`
```

and

```
image = readClipboard(format=2, raw=TRUE)
```

but I always obtain a NULL value for image !
Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Does `image = readClipboard(format=8, raw=TRUE)` work for you?